# Why Plot is not a listable function but still take input as a list?

Tags: functions, attributes

By using `Attributes` I can see that the function `Plot` is not a `Listable` function.

```
Attributes[Plot]
```

> `{HoldAll,Protected,ReadProtected}`

However, why does `Plot` still allow to take a list of functions as an input as bellow?

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]},{x, 0, 2Pi}]
```

Comment: When something is `Listable`, it is threaded over lists.  So `func[{x1, x2, x3}]` evaluates to `{func[x1], func[x2], func[x3]}` if `func` is `Listable`.  `Plot` doesn't behave that way, but returns a single object in return.

Comment: Not having a `Listable` attribute does not imply that a function won't accept lists as arguments.